# Load sublime text packages depending on programming language

Tags: macos, vim, package-management, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I use sublime text’s [package control](https://sublime.wbond.net/) to install packages. After installing a bunch of them, its startup becomes a bit sluggish (and maybe it’s performance starts to degrade as well), and I’m thinking that it’s a waste of resources to load all of them all the time anyway, since for the most part they are language specific. [CSScomb](http://csscomb.com/) is useless unless I’m editing a CSS file, yet it loads the plugin anyway.

In vim, with a package manager like NeoBundle, we can do something like

```
NeoBundleLazy 'csscomb/csscomb-for-vim'
autocmd FileType css NeoBundleSource csscomb-for-vim
```

That will only load that package when the filetype matches what we specify (even if we change the filetype while editing). Is there any equivalent for Sublime Text?

Comment: The vimscript part of `csscomb-for-vim` is 9 lines long. Even if it *should* be an `ftplugin` instead of a `plugin` (bad design but harmless in this case), lazy-loading it won't provide much in terms of performance. And using another plugin to fix the design mistakes of a plugin's author sounds weird to me. Anyway, the ST version is not that big either, if ST has an issue tracker you should use it to ask for that (rather obvious) feature.

Comment: CSScomb is used as an example, it’s not the only one I use this on. If I have dozens on plugins and I lazy-load only the ones I need depending on the filetype, performance is noticeably better. Regarding the use of a plugin, I’m not using it for lazy-loading, I’m using it for package management, and lazy-loading is a useful feature it has.

Comment: Lazyloading is a hack. Vim has ftplugin and autoload which deal with filetype specific stuff easily and dare I say elegantly. If a filetype specific plugin doesn't use those mechanisms it is poorly written.

Comment: Perhaps, but either way we’re getting sidetracked since vim is not the issue here, Sublime Text is.

Comment: And I gave you an advice regarding ST: if that feature doesn't exist, ask for it using whatever channel is suited to that kind of request.

Comment: I don’t know if it exists — hence the question. I don’t care if it cannot be done via Package Control, I’m asking if anyone knows of a way to accomplish it, using Package Control or not.